# CONSULTA UNIENDO VARIAS COLUMNAS

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla con 5 columnas...

Realizo una búsqueda en la base de datos a través de la siguiente linea donde
$buscar contiene el criterio de búsqueda que deseo realizar.

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM bdfo WHERE piso LIKE '%$buscar%' OR sala LIKE 
      '%$buscar%' OR fila LIKE '%$buscar%' OR posicion_de_fila LIKE 
      '%$buscar%' OR usuario LIKE '%$buscar%'" );
```

Si en mi variable ingreso "03", me muestra exactamente las filas que contienen dicho registro, de igual manera para cada una de las columnas.

Hasta acá todo marcha bien, lo que necesito que al momento de yo ingresar en la variable "03 T 102A..." me muestre de igual forma resultados para ir disminuyendo los registros en la tabla.

Gracias!

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente.. Cuando realizo una búsqueda con la siguiente linea, obtengo el siguiente resultado.

$sql=("SELECT * FROM bdfo WHERE piso LIKE '%$buscar%' OR sala LIKE '%$buscar%' OR fila LIKE '%$buscar%' OR posicion_de_fila LIKE '%$buscar%' OR usuario LIKE '%$buscar%'" );

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que al realizar la siguiente búsqueda mas especifica me muestre resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y en ese caso qué problema tienes?

Comment: ¿Buscas que se realice la búsqueda por "%03 T 102A%" o por "%03%" ,"%T%", "%102A%"?¿Buscas que se realice la búsqueda por cualquiera de esos términos?. Seria útil que dieras ejemplos de que sucede en tu búsqueda de "03" y  "03 T 102A..."  sin mayor información dudo que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: si buscas mediante varios términos podrías probar revisar la siguiente pregunta en [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129355/like-wildcard-with-multiple-fields-and-spaces-in-mysql)

Comment: Lo que necesito es que la busqueda me de resultados en ambos casos, agrego algunas capturas de pantalla de lo que necesito.

Comment: Interpreto que lo que quieres es que si introduces varios términos en la caja de texto, que busque en las cinco columnas por cada uno de los términos que introduces, no?

Comment: Efectivamente @snucka

Comment: Hay algún requisito a mayores? Si buscas `T 03` debería aparecer el mismo registro?

Answer (score 0):

Joel, según lo que interpreto, deberías hacer una consulta dinámica, en la que por cada palabra distinta que se incluya en el criterio de búsqueda, añadieses una condición en tu consulta SQL.

Esto es, Cuando recuperes lo que el usuario ha introducido en la búsqueda, por medio de la función split (puedes ver una referencia [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.split.php))

Generarás un array con los distintos términos introducidos.

Una vez con ello, deberías recorrer este array y por cada término ir añadiendo la condición a tu sentencia SQL.

Como ejemplo, te indico si tu array tuviese 3 términos de búsqueda, la sentencia debería quedar así:

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM bdfo WHERE 
            (piso LIKE '%$buscar1%' OR 
             sala LIKE '%$buscar1%' OR 
             fila LIKE '%$buscar1%' OR 
 posicion_de_fila LIKE '%$buscar1%' OR 
          usuario LIKE '%$buscar1%') 

   OR 

            (piso LIKE '%$buscar2%' OR 
             sala LIKE '%$buscar2%' OR 
             fila LIKE '%$buscar2%' OR 
 posicion_de_fila LIKE '%$buscar2%' OR 
          usuario LIKE '%$buscar2%') 

   OR 
            (piso LIKE '%$buscar3%' OR 
             sala LIKE '%$buscar3%' OR 
             fila LIKE '%$buscar3%' OR 
 posicion_de_fila LIKE '%$buscar3%' OR
          usuario LIKE '%$buscar3%')" );
```

Dónde "$buscar1", "$buscar2", "$buscar3"... son los distintos términos que ha introducido el usuario.

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tomas el texto de la caja, lo extraes en las palabras entradas (un split). Luego haces un ciclo (for) y por cada termino generas la misma consulta, concatenando los resultados en un array que tengas fuera del ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que te sería bastante más fácil sacar TODOS los datos de la tabla en el caso de que no sea una tabla muy grande y usar el plugin de DataTables https://datatables.net/.

Por otra parte Si lo que quieres es hacer una consulta cada vez que se busque algo, entonces es separar los strings de busqueda por espacios con un split.